# Add new data (not update) to Firebase

Tags: java, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I have a code that sends data to DataBase firebase. Its disadvantage is that it overwrites the data with each new send (update), and I would like the data to be added.

I am capturing data with okhttp3. File mainativity.kt shows how it happens
How can I do that?

Also at the end of the question, for clarity, I added the result that is transferred to the base

```
    class PSInterceptor(
    private val deviceId: String = "unknown device",
    private val userId: String = "unknown user",
    private val sessionId: String = "unknown session",
) :
    Interceptor {

    @Throws(IOException::class)
    override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
        val request: Request = chain.request()
        val t1 = System.nanoTime()
        val response: Response = chain.proceed(request)
        val t2 = System.nanoTime()
        val requestMap = mapOf(
            "timestamp" to t1,
            "duration" to t2 - t1,
            "protocol" to chain.connection()?.protocol()?.name.toString(),
            "request" to mapOf(
                "method" to request.method,
                "url" to request.url,
                "headers" to request.headers.toString(),
                "body" to request.body.toString(),
                "size" to request.body.toString().length,
            ),
            "response" to mapOf(
                "code" to response.code.toString(),
                "headers" to response.headers.toString(),
                "body" to response.body?.string(),
                "size" to response.body.toString().length,
            ),
        )
       
        firebasePush(requestMap)
        return response
    }

    fun firebasePush(requestMap: Map<String, Any?>): Boolean {
        val db = Firebase.database
        val myRef = db.getReference(deviceId).child(userId).child(sessionId)
        myRef.setValue(requestMap)
        return true
    }
}}
```

Comment: setValue will always overwrite data.  Have you read the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#updating_or_deleting_data) thoroughly?

Comment: @DougStevenson Thanks for the answer, but in my case this solution does not work

Comment: Are you saying that you used updateChildren, and it didn't work the way you expect?  I think it would help if you update the question to explain what exactly is happening that's different than what you want, and explain what exactly you want it to do instead.  Be specific and show actual data.  We can't see the values in your variables, and we can't see the contents of your database.

Comment: @DougStevenson Yes, I have updated the code in the question.
At the moment the code I'm using is overwriting (updating) the values (same happens with updateChildren). But my goal is that the values in firebase are added, that is, that the previous values \u200b\u200bare saved and new ones are added.

Comment: I'm assuming that the JSON you posted is what you get from the code you shared. If so, can you edit your question to also show: 1) the JSON that is in the database *before* the write operation, 2) the JSON that you want to exist in the database *after* the write operation?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Yes, JSON the file is the output of my code. I added my expectations. That is, I would like it to be possible to add data with the same key. Thank you for your help

Comment: That structure is not possible. In JSON, each key is unique under its parent. If you want to build a list of children, have a look at Firebase's `push()` operation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#append_to_a_list_of_data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Doug commented, calling `setValue()` will always replace the data at the reference/path with the data you pass to the call. If you want to update specific children under the path, you can use `updateChildren()` instead.

So this will replace the values of any keys in your `requestMap`, but will leave any other child nodes of `myRef` unmodified:

```
myRef.updateChildren(requestMap)
```

Comment: I'm sorry, maybe you misunderstood me, because Kotlin is not my main language, and I don't know much about this language. At the moment, my code just updates (overwrites the data). And I need new data to be added to the previous data (so that the previous ones remain, and the new one is added)

Comment: Yes, that's what the code in my answer does. Did you run it?

Comment: @yes, of course!

Comment: I added some code to the question, maybe it will make it clearer what the reason is

Comment: Yes, JSON the file is the output of my code. I added my expectations. That is, I would like it to be possible to add data with the same key. Thank you for your help